# MySQL: select maximum year value from my table?

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
ID           Value       Year
10           Singapore   2010
10           Malaysia    2009
10           India       2008
```

Now I want to retrieve maximum year record only.

Example:

```
ID             value       year
10             Singapore   2010
```

How can I write query in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from tbl order by year desc limit 1
```

assuming year is unique